# How to take an element over to given padding with CSS

Tags: html, css

In the below image. I've given 10px padding to container because most of the time I need that padding. only the headings (blue) I don't need padding. How to extend heading over padding?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeSHZ.jpg

I don't want to give individual padding to each element inside container.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to create a graphic! Makes life easy.

Comment: Can anyone suggest better title for this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Negative margin on the headings.

**See on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2cdJ/**

**CSS**

```
div {
  background: red;  
  padding:10px;
  width:200px; 
}
p {
  background: green;   
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 -10px;   
  background: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph.</p>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>    
    <p>This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph.</p>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    <p>This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it the only way? negative margin on right side? actually the layout is fluid so if i give margin in %?

Comment: You can use margins in % or px.

Comment: but I want to stretch heading on both side not only on one side. what width will be of `#container`, heading should automatically stretch to the `#container` wall

Comment: You could also accomplish this using relative positioning, however, I think the negative margin solution is much simpler.

Comment: @jessegavin - negative margins are making horizontal scrollbar

Comment: @Jitendra, sorry that is happening for you. In the example I have provided above that doesn't happen. There must be some other factors in your particular situation. Hard for me to know. Perhaps you could create a separate question for that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same code as jessegavin did . I used relative and absolute positioning

see it on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f2cdJ/)

CSS

```
div {
 background: red;  
 padding:10px;
 width:200px;
 position:relative;
}
p {
 background: green;   
}
h2 {
 background: blue;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <p>This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. </p>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>    
    <p>This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. </p>
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    <p>This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. This is the paragraph. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [jessegavin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711930/how-to-take-an-element-over-to-given-padding-with-css/5711940#5711940) said, use negative margins.

Negative margins are funky, but they work properly. You'd have to include the `10px` padding twice (once for the left, another time for the right padding) into the `width` of the heading, and then do a negative `margin-left`:

```
margin-left: -10px;
```